# Makefile: always run prerequisite for a rule?

Tags: makefile

I'm wondering if there's a way for to have `make` always run some rule before another if it's a prerequisite.

For example:

```
setup:
    @echo "Setup"
    
rule1: setup
    @echo "Rule 1"

rule2: setup
    @echo "Rule 2"
```

Running make with the above Makefile, outputs:

```
Setup
Rule 1
Rule 2
```

But I want setup to be run before Rule 2 as well. With would produce an output like this:

```
Setup
Rule 1
Setup
Rule 2
```

Is calling `make setup` inside the command list my only option?

Comment: `.PHONY` is one way to force it, but if none of these rules create targets with those names, you don't even have to make it a `.PHONY:`; just declare a dependency and `make` will notice that the file doesn't exist, and rerun the recipe.

Comment: As an aside, littering your Makefile with `@` is just making debugging harder. If you find yourself doing that a lot, probably better to get in the habit of using `make -s` when you don't want to be able to debug.

Comment: .PHONY doesn't work. the `setup` rule is only ever executed once per call to `make`. thanks for the "-s" tip.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread the question. Maybe you can synthesize multiple targets like `setup-%:` and have your individual targets depend on `setup-1` and `setup-2` but this is quite tortured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern rule and the GNU make secondary expansion could provide an approximation. As you cannot build the same target several times the idea is to have as many `setup-ruleN` targets as there are `ruleN` targets, and to use the same `setup-%` pattern rule for all `setup-ruleN`:

```sh
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: all
all: rule1 rule2

setup-%:
    @echo "Setup"
    
.SECONDEXPANSION:

rule1: setup-$$@
    @echo "Rule 1"

rule2: setup-$$@
    @echo "Rule 2"

$ make
Setup
Rule 1
Setup
Rule 2
```

Bonus: the `$*` automatic variable can be used in the `setup-%` recipe, in case you would like to personalize it:

```sh
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: all
all: rule1 rule2

setup-%:
    @echo "Setup ($*)"
    
.SECONDEXPANSION:

rule1: setup-$$@
    @echo "Rule 1"

rule2: setup-$$@
    @echo "Rule 2"

$ make
Setup (rule1)
Rule 1
Setup (rule2)
Rule 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have a target built more than one time per invocation of make.

If you have a "preamble" you want to run before each rule then you can put it into a variable and add the variable into every recipe:

```
SETUP = @echo "Setup"

rule1:
        $(SETUP)
        @echo "Rule 1"

rule2:
        $(SETUP)
        @echo "Rule 2"
```